# Selenium framework in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium-webdriver, jasmine, protractor

Cuurently i have a framework which is a Maven project supporting Selenium and TestNG. It is coded in Java and final execution is done via Jenkins.

Now, we have to develop a new framework for a new project with all these capabilities, but to be coded in JavaScript since people writing test cases in new project wants to use Javascript as a language and new website is written in Angular JS.

I am not able to find anything to create a new maven project for selenium/testNg using javascript. What am i missing. Am i going in wrong direction and i should be using some other tools like protractor etc? Please guide.

Comment: Did you try this [JS](http://webdriver.io/)

Comment: seems more like simple code without maven. My start point is creating a maven project that supports javascript. Writing cases is second step.

Comment: Check if this helps : https://github.com/akquinet/javascript-archetypes

Comment: I've personally used Protractor with AngularJS and they go together very well. Its my goto for E2E tests in AngularJS.